NOT FOUND. The requested URL was not found
Mini Notes App has two pages, Homepage and About page. While the Home page works, the about page does not. It displays the message: NOT FOUND. The requested URL was not found.
This is the 'controllers/index.php' file.
<?php

$heading = 'Home';

require 'views/index.view.php'; 

This is the corresponding 'views/index.view.php' file
<?php require('partials/head.php') ?>
  
<?php require('partials/nav.php') ?>
<?php require('partials/banner.php') ?>


  <main>
       <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          Welcome to the Zanga
         </div>`
     </main>

 <?php require('partials/footer.php') ?>

This is the 'index.php' file
require 'functions.php';
<?php

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
$routes = [
    '/' => 'controllers/index.php',
    '/about' => 'controllers/about.php',
];

function routeToController($uri, $routes) {
    if (array_key_exists($uri, $routes)) {
        require $routes[$uri];
    } else {
        abort();
    }

}


function abort($code = 404) {
    http_response_code($code);

    require "views/{$code}.php";

    die();
}

routeToController($uri, $routes);

This is the 'views/about.view.php
<?php require('partials/head.php') ?>

<?php require('partials/nav.php') ?>
<?php require('partials/banner.php') ?>
  
 <main>
     <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
         You are on the about page
         </div>
     </main>

<?php require('partials/footer.php') ?>

I thoroughly analysed routes for any bugs but all in vain. 'controllers/about.php' always displays 'Not Found. Requested URL not found.
I tried to duplicate the website but it still displays . Not Found. The requested URL was not found in chrome.

To debug this, first determine who is throwing the 404 error, either Apache or PHP. I think this is the former, but I'm not 100% certain. If it is the former, then your server config is most likely not correct. If the latter, your code isn't defining this route correctly.

Please [edit] your post and clean up the formatting.. I tried but it's a mess. Use 3 backticks on new lines before and after the code to format it properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Your edit was better, but still way too many code fences. I've cleaned it up, please [edit] if there's any data missing.

For your main index.php router to handle all requests, you need to tell your webserver to pass all incoming reqeusts to that file, so when handling a request for /about, it passes the request to index.php, and does not simply look for a file called /about on disk.  This is usually done with .htaccess for Apache, and try_files in a location block in nginx.  Maybe you're aware of this, but you haven't mentioned it, and it's a key part of what you're doing.  If you've done this, edit your question and add details.  If not, this will be the problem.

@ChrisHaas the issue has been resolved. The solution can be seen below. Thank you...

I was able to resolve the issue '404 NOT FOUND. The requested url was not found' by setting up URL re-writing using Apache and a '.htaccess' file in `the root directory. It allowed the web server to redirect requests for specific URLs to the appropriate PHP file. Thus;
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

I created '.htaccess' file in the root directory of the project and used the code above and saved it. The 'controllers/about.php' is now working. The code enabled URL rewriting in Apache, and made it to redirect allrequests that are not for existing files or directories to
index.php , with the original URL appended as a parameter.

Before doing anything else, could you please test the code by running a local PHP server?
Open a terminal at the root of your project and type the following command:
php -S localhost:8000

Try navigating to it. If it doesn't work, take a look at the code below that I have recreated.
// controllers/index.php
<?php

$heading = 'Home';

require './views/index.view.php'; 

<?php
// controllers/about.php
$heading = 'About';

require 'views/about.view.php'; 

// views/index.view.php 
<?php require('partials/head.php') ?>

<?php require('partials/nav.php') ?>
<?php require('partials/banner.php') ?>
  
 <main>
     <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
         Welcome to the Zanga
         </div>
     </main>

<?php require('partials/footer.php') ?>

// views/about.view.php 
<?php require('partials/head.php') ?>

<?php require('partials/nav.php') ?>
<?php require('partials/banner.php') ?>
  
     <main>
         <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            You are on the about page
         </div>
     </main>

<?php require('partials/footer.php') ?>

<?php
// index.php
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
$routes = [
    '/' => 'controllers/index.php',
    '/about' => 'controllers/about.php',
];

function routeToController($uri, $routes) {
    if (array_key_exists($uri, $routes)) {
        require $routes[$uri];
    } else {
        abort();
    }

}


function abort($code = 404) {
    http_response_code($code);

    require "views/{$code}.php";

    die();
}

routeToController($uri, $routes);


What is the difference between the code posted by the OP and this code? A quick scan through shows them to be identical? If they are identical, then I think you are ultimately saying "test this on your local machine, here's how", which really should be a comment, not an answers. If there's something significant that you've change, please call it out.

Sorry this is the first time I've helped someone on StackOverFlow.
I tried to reproduce the error on my side, but without success.  I concluded that it might be the web server (Apache or Nginx) that is misconfigured.
I’ve re-added the code because the original author didn’t include the files for the "about" page. I also added comments indicating the names of the files.

We all have to start somewhere, so I'm glad you put yourself out there, and I hope this doesn't dissuade you from answering in the future. To your answer, "try this..." kind of solutions are usually better as comments (which I know you can't do you yet). Also, when posting code, especially if it is very similar, notes/comments should be added explaining what was change/add/removed.

Maybe that you have not yet read  how to answer?  You can find useful infos there
